# Issue with req in Next.js 13 when using stripe webhook handler

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

Description:
I am encountering a problem with the req.headers and content in my Stripe webhook handler using Next.js 13. The code is not correctly retrieving the req.headers or any content within req. I am using the stripe.webhooks.constructEvent method to process the webhook event, but it seems to be failing.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import Stripe from "stripe";
import { connectToDB } from "@utils/database";
import Job from "@models/job";
import { buffer } from 'micro';

// Set up Stripe
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};

export const POST = async (req) => {
    let event;

    if (process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET) {
        const signature = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
        const buf = await buffer(req);
        try {
            event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
                buf,
                signature,
                process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
            );
            // Handle the specific event type
            if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
                console.log("Checkout session completed");
                const session = event.data.object;
                const jobData = session.metadata.jobData;

                // Save the job post to the database
                try {
                    await connectToDB();
                    const newJob = new Job(jobData);
                    await newJob.save();
                    console.log("Job post saved:", newJob);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error("Failed to save job post:", error);
                }
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Failed to parse request body:", error);
        }
    }
};
```

I have noticed that the req.headers and any content within req are not being properly accessed.

The error I'm getting is:

`error HttpError: Invalid body at createError (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/micro/dist/src/lib/index.js:33:17)`

I'm also receiving the checkout.session.completed event. The stripe webhook key is correct without any spaces.

```
2023-06-24 10:34:33   --\> checkout.session.completed

2023-06-24 10:34:33  \<--  \[500\] POST http://localhost:3000/api/stripe-webhooks%60
```

I'm not sure where is the issue here. When I'm console.log the req.headers I'm getting:

```
req headers HeadersList {
  cookies: null,
  [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(15) {
    'accept' => { name: 'accept', value: '*/*; q=0.5, application/xml' },
    'cache-control' => { name: 'cache-control', value: 'no-cache' },
    'connection' => { name: 'connection', value: 'close' },
    'content-type' => { name: 'content-type', value: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    'host' => { name: 'host', value: 'localhost:3000' },
    'stripe-signature' => {
      name: 'stripe-signature',
      value: 't=1687592522,v1=d179a34e628bc9245bb13d09c7cf0dca99cb53836ac866be14dfd7932a123b4e,v0=68445fef4a5de776cbce64fcee197ab8a425c3390684108a57b767726bf96925'
    },
    'transfer-encoding' => { name: 'transfer-encoding', value: 'chunked' },
    'user-agent' => {
      name: 'user-agent',
      value: 'Stripe/1.0 (+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)'
    },
    'x-forwarded-for' => { name: 'x-forwarded-for', value: '::1' },
    'x-forwarded-host' => { name: 'x-forwarded-host', value: 'localhost:3000' },
    'x-forwarded-port' => { name: 'x-forwarded-port', value: '3000' },
    'x-forwarded-proto' => { name: 'x-forwarded-proto', value: 'http' },
    'x-invoke-path' => { name: 'x-invoke-path', value: '/api/stripe-webhooks' },
    'x-invoke-query' => { name: 'x-invoke-query', value: '%7B%7D' },
    'x-middleware-invoke' => { name: 'x-middleware-invoke', value: '' }
  },
  [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: [
    [ 'accept', '*/*; q=0.5, application/xml' ],
    [ 'cache-control', 'no-cache' ],
    [ 'connection', 'close' ],
    [ 'content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ],
    [ 'host', 'localhost:3000' ],
    [
      'stripe-signature',
      't=1687592522,v1=d179a34e628bc9245bb13d09c7cf0dca99cb53836ac866be14dfd7932a123b4e,v0=68445fef4a5de776cbce64fcee197ab8a425c3390684108a57b767726bf96925'
    ],
    [ 'transfer-encoding', 'chunked' ],
    [ 'user-agent', 'Stripe/1.0 (+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)' ],
    [ 'x-forwarded-for', '::1' ],
    [ 'x-forwarded-host', 'localhost:3000' ],
    [ 'x-forwarded-port', '3000' ],
    [ 'x-forwarded-proto', 'http' ],
    [ 'x-invoke-path', '/api/stripe-webhooks' ],
    [ 'x-invoke-query', '%7B%7D' ],
    [ 'x-middleware-invoke', '' ]
  ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of `signature` parameter? Did you get the value in the format of `t=xxx,v1=xxx,v0=xxx`?

Comment: The way you retrieve the event body doesn't correct. It shouldn't be entire `req` putting into buffer. It should just simply be the request body alone, i.e. `req.body` when setting into `stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(..)` function. For example, `event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, signature, process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET);`